# Meteor: Get query parameters from url on server? Use case Instagram oAuth

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

This is easy to do with a client side router or JS on the client. But since window is not an object on the server how would one get a query parameter or even read a url from the server? I checked node examples but couldn't find anything that didn't pertain to express js.

My use case is Instagram, It sends me back a code that needs to be read on the server and then I send a http request with that code from the server to retrieve an access token.

Has to be on page load, not load then send to server via client.

Basically I want to retrieve the query of "code" http://localhost:3000/?code=5e04c2e304f24f8b8380c2ec81202139 on the server.

Comment: Are you using Meteor?

Comment: Yea sorry, forgot to mention that, updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the [Instagram instruction for authentication](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/), it seems that you are using the Server-side flow. I do not know why you choose this over the Client-side authentication flow which seems to be more appropriate, I think you should re-consider which method to use. Anyway, to answer your question you could use [`WebApp`](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html) package to define a server route in Meteor:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/", function(req, res, next) {
  if (req._parsedUrl.pathname === '/') {
    const code = req.query.code;
    console.log(code);

    // get ACCESS_TOKEN with code

    // if you need to redirect user after authorization
    // res.writeHead(302, {
    //   Location: '/route/after/authorization'
    // });
    // res.end();
  }

  // comment this if you redirect to another route
  next();
});
```

Comment: It is a requirement upon request, that is why I went with server side flow. I'll try this out soon and if it works out. I will accept. Thanks for the efforts in advance.

Really cool I had never even seen that part of the meteor docs before.